# How to store and query data with varying structures

Tags: sql-server, schema, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

I have an project where I need to have multiple lists of people. One list might include first name, last name, email address while another list will store last name, email, birthday, company, account number, etc. In other works, each list has a different structure. The users of this project are allowed to create an unlimited number of lists and up to 100 attributes for people in the list.

Additionally, users can query filtered lists that only return a portion of the people in the list based on attribute values. Each attribute can be text, number, or date.

In my old system, I had 2 tables.

- List
- ListPeople (contains up to 10 million records or so)

In the ListPeople table, I would have 100 columns:

- value1 nvarchar(255)
- value2 nvarchar(255)
- ...

The problem is that when they build queries to filter the data, each query would be forced to do a table scan since I didn't index every column.

What is the best approach to handle this? Should I just keep my schema and add indexes to all columns (lots of inserts/updates to this table) or design it differently? Maybe using EAV (hopefully not)? The other idea (since this will be in Azure) is to have a List table and ListPeople table but then also use a DocumentDB No-SQL database to store people's attributes. I'm just not sure if that would be the best approach.

Comment: Ever tried PeopleAttribute table with name/value columns?

Comment: This sounds like it should be built in a nosql database apposed to a sql database.

Comment: @AndrewO'Brien - what do you mean by "NoSQL"? What type? There are many. Also, the OP tagged with DocumentDB (a document store). But *why* should it be built with non-relational? Just saying to do so doesn't add any guidance; just an opinion (which, incidentally, is why this question is off-topic).

Comment: The reason I think this would be a good NoSQL project is because of the varying column structure and data types. It would need to be transferred to a SQL database for analytics, but purely for operations it seems much simpler with NoSQL.

Comment: ``1.each list has a different structure;2.users can query filtered lists that only return a portion of the people in the list based on attribute values; `` Azure Storage Table has a schemaless design and it enables us to partition data&perform partition query, which might be a approach to store your flexible datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, SQL Server (or any normal SQL based DB) is not the correct tool for this. Things like MongoDB or other NoSQL options would seem to be more correct for what you are describing.

However, assuming that you must use Azure, I'd start by looking at some of the newer table types, like a columnstore index table.

Alternately, the People_Attribute table structure (where one table holds "people", another holds Attribute names and information about the attributes, and the People_Attribute_Values table holds a pointer to a "people" record, a pointer to an "attribute" record, and the value of the attribute for that person. Although this can get unwieldy, it is fully indexed.

Comment: What do you mean, "columnstore index table?" Also, the OP tagged as DocumentDB (which is a document store) - why would you discard that, and instead propose some type of pointer-to-attribute scheme?

Comment: A Columnstore Indexed table is a specialized type of table/index, available in SQL Server and Azure. It stores data in columns instead of rows (details are too complex for this small space). Originally designed to speed analytics, it seems like it could be useful in this scenario.  As for discarding the DocumentDB - I didn't. As I said in my answer, "...assuming that you must use Azure...", which this post is tagged for and which is a SQL Server derivative. So I was answering for that scenario, where the Azure DB / SQL Server was the primary driver of the database.